# What is the maximum length of a PDF document password?

Tags: pdf, pdfcreator, pdftk

I would like to know what is the maximum length of a PDF document password.

I want to know this, for all PDF document versions and encryption modes.

For example 40bit, 128bit, 256bit etc.

Comment: min 4 to maximum 32 chars..   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Connect/6.0/Enterprise/help.html?content=WS11d1def534ea1be08a52b610b38bfaa95-7dd1.html.

Comment: @Prasanna sounds like a (valid) answer; not like a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password length can be between 4 and 32 characters.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Connect/6.0/Enterprise/help.html?content=WS11d1def534ea1be08a52b610b38bfaa95-7dd1.html